# unusable array when passing a txt file into array

Tags: python, file

So i need to pass all elements(the all are strings) from txt file into an array to use further. I have this kind of output:

```
 ['mzm\n', 'vur\n', 'bmc\n', 'irl\n'],
```

but i have:

```
 KeyError: '\n' because of this '/n's.
```

Is it possible to pass all strings into array to have this output [mzm, vur, bmc, irl]?

This is for my radix sort algorithm.

```
def main():
    with open('Array.txt') as my_file:
        words = my_file.readlines()
    max_size = check_max_word_size(words)
    new_list = set_same_size(words, max_size)
    new_list = radix_sort(new_list, max_size-1, 0)
    #Remove the dots previously added to the words
    index = 0
    for word in new_list:
        new_list[index]= re.sub('[.]', '', word)
        index+=1
    #Print the final ordered list, all lower case
    print(new_list)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

[mzm, vur, bmc, irl]

Answer (score 0):

You can strip off the trailing newlines in `word` like this:

```
new_list[index]= re.sub('[.]', '', word.rstrip())
```

Answer (score 0):

The characters `'\n'` come from the file, as `readlines()` keeps them.

You can remove the characters `'\n'` like this:

```
words = [w.strip('\n') for w in words]
```

Comment: That works, thanks a lot. Maybe you know how to remove  ' '  this hooks